# Creating in an infinite loop using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can restart my loop after reaches the last item of the list. Basically it passes the class `active` to the next sibling every 3s. How can I make it pass to the first item on the list once it reaches the last item.

I was thinking maybe if I could have use `if/else` instead of `for` loop in my program

```js
$(document).ready(function() {



 function durationSlider() {
     var listItems = $('.loop ul li').length;

  for(count=0; count <= listItems - 1; count++ ) {
         
            (function(count) {
                setTimeout(function() {
     $('.loop ul li.active').removeClass('active');
     $('.loop ul li:eq(' + count +   ')').addClass('active'); 
     console.log(count);
                }, 3000 * count);
            }(count));
  }  
 }

 durationSlider();
    

})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


.loop ul li {
 color : green;
 -webkit-transition: color 1s linear;

}

.loop ul li.active {
 -webkit-transition: color 1s linear; 
    color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loop">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: if you're trying to make an infinite loop with `setTimeout` you might want ot use `setInterval` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `setInterval` instead of a for loop with `setTimeout`. Inside the interval we can add an if condition to reset the count when it reaches the end of your list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function durationSlider() {
    var listItems = $('.loop ul li').length;
    var count = 0;
     
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.loop ul li.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.loop ul li:eq(' + count +   ')').addClass('active'); 
        console.log(count);

        count += 1;
        if (count >= listItems) {
            count = 0;
        }
    }, 3000);

}

durationSlider();

})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


.loop ul li {
 color : green;
 -webkit-transition: color 1s linear;

}

.loop ul li.active {
 -webkit-transition: color 1s linear; 
    color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loop">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, sorry for my ignorance what is the difference using `setTimeout` and `setInterval`?

Comment: `setTimeout` is a one time execution after a specified number of milliseconds. `setInterval` will execute every time with the specified number of miliseconds (until it's stopped with `clearInterval`).

Answer (score 8):

Using pure JavaScript code

```
function start() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Hello My Infinite Loop Execution');

      // Again
      start();

      // Every 3 sec
    }, 3000);
}

// Begins
start();
```