# Having trouble setting timeout to infinity

Tags: javascript, html, gif

I have a spinner gif animation that runs on click. I want this gif to run until the function is finished and moves to the next page. Can anyone help with this? I have tried changing the time to 10000 but it did not work as it still was not long enough.

See code below

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout("hide()", 5000); // 5 seconds
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="show()">

<div id="myDiv" style="display:none"><img id="myImage" src="Spinner.gif"></div><br>
```

Comment: So you should be hide()'ing as the last statement in "the function"

Comment: The spinner gif is hidden until the user clicks submit, then the spinner shows for 5seconds but I would like this to be longer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating in an infinite loop using setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227997/creating-in-an-infinite-loop-using-settimeout)

Comment: If you are navigating to a new page why do you need to hide the spinner at all?

Comment: side note: it should be written as `setTimeout(hide, 5000);` without the quotes and parentheses

Comment: yes your right @Deadron I removed the timeout and it worked. It now displays until the function ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use  setTimeout. Just call hide() function in the end of  function which you wait for

Comment: Thanks, i was able to remove the timeout and this worked